# Spring cloud sleuth with Webservicetemplate

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

Does Spring cloud sleuth support WebserviceTemplate? I mean - I have a service which makes 2 service calls - One using RestTemplate and another using Webservicetemplate. The Rest call is getting displayed in Zipkin and the Soap call using Webservicetemplate is not. Do I have to add @NewSpan to all my soap calls ? Is it not automatically done like Resttemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - we haven't added any instrumentation around Webservicetemplate. You'd have to add an interceptor similar to the one we add for RestTemplate. You'd have to pass all the tracing headers to the request so that the other side can properly parse it.

Comment: I have two calls to a webservice using Webservicetemplate. I annotated the two methods making the webservice calls using @NewSpan. I see that only one service call gets  sent to zipkin. See below for the trace information. In the second webservice call, parent span is null. Did I make a mistake ? Trace for first call - $[Trace: ca919fe522d78d9f, Span: 2d1c34fa53ac7fa6, Parent: ca919fe522d78d9f, exportable:true], For second call - [Trace: ca919fe522d78d9f, Span: ca919fe522d78d9f, Parent: null, exportable:true]

Comment: I can't help you without a sample. I have no idea what you're doing

Comment: I was having 2 @NewSpan annotation in the same class. I guess that was the problem. I saw one of your other posts where you have said it wont work. I moved one of the NewSpan to another class and it started working

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for writing about it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use spring cloud sleuth with Webservicetemplate,

if service A sends a request to service B,

At first you'll send the trace id in the header of the sent request by the below code

```
@Service
public class WebServiceMessageCallbackImpl implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;

public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws TransformerException {
    Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
    String traceId = span.context().traceId();
    SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
    SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
    StringSource headerSource = new StringSource("<traceId>" + traceId + "</traceId>");
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
}
}
```

then in service B, you'll create an interceptor, then read the trace id from the header of the coming request, then put this trace id in the MDC like in the below code

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class HttpInterceptor2 extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final String traceId = "traceId";
@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    String payload = new String(request.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String traceId = traceId(payload);
    MDC.put("traceId", traceId);

    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        MDC.remove(traceId);
    }

}

private String traceId(String payload) {
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

    if (payload.contains(traceId)) {

        int index = payload.indexOf(traceId);

        while (index < payload.length() && payload.charAt(index) != '>') {
            index++;
        }
        index++;

        for (int i = index; ; i++) {
            if (payload.charAt(i) == '<') {
                break;
            }
            token.append(payload.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    if (token.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        token.append(traceId());
    }
    return token.toString().trim();

}

private String traceId() {
    Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
    String traceId = span.context().traceId();
    return traceId;
}

}
```