# Spring Cloud Sleuth instrumentation for Spring-WS (SOAP) services

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Is there a way to instrument a SOAP web-service (written with Spring-ws) using Spring Cloud Sleuth?

It doesn't seem to work out of the box like REST services do. Any pointers on how to wrap Sleuth instrumentation around it would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use soap with spring sleuth as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71403869/13750762